# Delete all items from an Azure CosmosDB container with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there a way to delete all items from an Azure CosmosDB container (collection)? I tried it so many way, but I got `azure.cosmos.errors.CosmosHttpResponseError`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet that worked for me. I hope it helps you.

### Code

```
# Importing the required libraries
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient

# Defining some key parameters
URL = 'your_url'
KEY = 'your_key'
DATABASE_NAME = 'your_database_name'
CONTAINER_NAME = 'your_container_name'
PARTITION_KEY = 'your_partition_key'

# Initializing the client
client = CosmosClient(URL, credential=KEY)

# Getting the database
database = client.get_database_client(DATABASE_NAME)

# Getting the container (collection)
container = database.get_container_client(CONTAINER_NAME)

# Iterating all the items of a container
for item in container.query_items(query='SELECT * FROM c', enable_cross_partition_query=True):

    # Deleting the current item
    container.delete_item(item, partition_key = item[PARTITION_KEY])
```

[Library refenrece](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-cosmos/4.0.0b5/index.html) | [GitHub link that resolved my issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/8327)

Comment: Or...you could just delete the container and recreate it.

Comment: You are right, but I can imagine that there are some cases when it is impossible or doesn't make sense. E.g., I don't have permission to delete it, or if you need to delete certain items, the code above can be a great starting point. :)

Comment: Agreed. One suggestion I would make is to look into bulk/batch API in this case. Your deletes would be much faster.